# PubSub preventing app engine from running

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on a google cloud project that involves moving data from pubsub, 
splitting the packet into several pieces and submitting each individual
piece to datastore. Datastore and the splitting parts work just fine, but when it comes to getting the message from pubsub, the window just keeps loading with no result. I've let it run for a while now and the request does not time out.

I tried including the `subscription.on` inside a `setInterval`call so that I can switch it off and on for a span of time, but this does not prevent the app from stalling.

Could this be happening because the `subscription.on` function is running continuously, not exiting and allowing express (the framework generating the app engine's page) to generate the page? If so, how can I avert this? What other approach could I be taking to successfully get data from pubsub?

I'm willing to provide more details if necessary. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Including pubsub call

```
var psMessage = '';
subscription.on('message', function(message) {
    psMessage = message;
    message.ack();
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code snippet including how you are receiving the pubsub messages? From your sentence "but when it comes to getting the message from pubsub, the window just keeps loading ..." can you clarify what is the "window" you are mentioning? Is it the App Engine GUI?

Comment: @Yurci I've edited in my pubsub call to my original post. The window I'm referring to is a web browser tab that is activated when you click on the current version in the app engine console. When I don't include my pubsub call, express returns a basic html document. When I include the pubsub call, the html never loads, leaving me with a white screen & no data.

Comment: Can you check which version of Pub/Sub Node.js client library are you using? [Version 0.19.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/pubsub/v/0.19.0) is the latest.  I've come across a similar [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/10) with older versions but this should have been fixed now with the new versions.

Comment: I've been using the same version as the one listed. However, I realized that my subscription was set to push when it was supposed to be pull. Now it works fine